# Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$ under the conditions $|f'(x)|\leq 1/x$ and $\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{R}\int_0^R|f(x)|dx=0$

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, derivatives

I encountered a problem while working on a mathematical analysis exercise. I wish to share this problem because of its interest, while it is a simple statement I feel  it is not straightforward to answer :

Given $f\in C^1([0,+\infty])$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq 1/x$ and $\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{R}\int_0^R |f(x)|dx=0$, how can we prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this question should be closed : it is an interesting and non trivial exercise, well explained by the author who asked for help and that was answered by myself after spending some time to do so, it's a shame to waste such contributions to the community.

Answer (score 4):

Put $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$. For any $\lambda>1$ and $n\in\mathbb N$ there exists $c_{\lambda,n}\in ]\lambda^n;\lambda^{n+1}[$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{F(\lambda^{n+1})-F(\lambda^n)}{\lambda^{n+1}-\lambda^n}=f(c_{\lambda,n})$ and from the second assumption, as $\lambda^{n+1}-\lambda^n=\lambda^{n+1}(1-1/\lambda)$, we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f(c_{\lambda,n})=0$.
From the first assumption we have for any $y>x>0$, $|f(y)-f(x)|\leq \ln(y)-\ln(x); (1)$. Let $(x_n)$ any sequence going to infinity : for any $k$ great enough there exists an integer $n_k$ such that $x_k\in [\lambda^{n_k};\lambda^{n_k+1}]$ hence from (1) we get $|f(x_k)-f(c_{\lambda,n_k})|\leq |\ln(x_k)-\ln(c_{\lambda,n_k})|\leq \ln(\lambda^{n_k+1})-\ln(\lambda^{n_k})$ which gives  $|f(x_k)-f(c_{\lambda,n_k})|\leq \ln(\lambda)$ and thus $|f(x_k)|\leq |f(c_{\lambda,n_k})|+\ln(\lambda)$. Letting $k\rightarrow +\infty$ you have then $\limsup_{k\rightarrow +\infty}|f(x_k)|\leq \ln(\lambda)$ for any $\lambda>1$ which entails $\limsup_{k\rightarrow +\infty}|f(x_k)|=0$. So $\lim f(x_n)=0$ and $(x_n)$ being any sequence in $\mathbb R_+$ going to infinity we finally get the conclusion.